# Derivative of the composition of two functions

Tags: derivatives

Is the calculation below valid?

\begin{align}
f(x)=ax+b+g(f(x))\\
\frac{df(x)}{dx}=a+\frac{dg(f(x))}{df(x)}\frac{df(x)}{dx}\\
\frac{df(x)}{dx}-\frac{dg(f(x))}{df(x)}\frac{df(x)}{dx}=a\\
\frac{df(x)}{dx}=\frac{a}{1-\frac{dg(f(x))}{df(x)}}\\
\end{align}
assuming $\frac{dg(f(x))}{df(x)} \neq 1$

Thanks a lot.

Comment: In the second line $\frac{dg(x)}{df(x)}$ should be $\frac{dg(f(x))}{df(x)}$.

Comment: @JamesPak You are right!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i have the same: $$f'(x)=a+g'(f(x))f'(x)$$ thus we obtain
$$f'(x)(1-g'(f(x))=a$$